# Finding a bijection in order to prove the cardinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $M=\{f\in\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}:\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0,f \; \text{is monotonic}\}$. I need to prove that $|M|=\aleph$. In order to do so, I need to find a bijection but can't think of one.

Comment: Do you mean $\aleph_0$?

Comment: @Arthur Probably $\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$. That's called $\aleph$ in some parts of the world.

Comment: @DanielFischer Really ? Where to they call it that ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus At least in Israel it's not uncommon, as I've learnt from Asaf Karagila.

Comment: @DanielFischer I never would have thought that. I spent a whole year in Israel (and doing set theory), and I cannot recall ever seeing this notation.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Probably too advanced. If memory serves, Asaf said that it's used in introductory courses [almost] exclusively.

Comment: @Rene: Uri and Matti used it often in the basic set theory course in BGU. If I recall correctly, the notation goes back to Hausdorff.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Funny story: I went to dinner with my neighbors who were students in Uri's logic course. One of them turns to me and asks if I have heard of aleph-0, explaining that aleph is the first letter of the Hebrew alphabet and 0, well, thats just zero. Have I heard of that? I said yes, I know about aleph-0 and aleph-1. Her eyes go wide open and she says with surprise There is also aleph-1 ??! I said yes and she turns around to her friends and says: Hey, this guy listen to this he says there is also an aleph-1!

Comment: @Rene: Awesome story! Ha! :)

Answer (score 4):

Let some of your functions be $f(n)=\begin {cases} \frac 1{2^n}\\ \frac {3/2}{2^n} \end {cases}$.  You can make the choice independently for each value of $n$, so there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ functions in this class.  The $3/2$ is chosen so the function will be monotonic whichever you choose.